# System.NotImplementedException: performActions in selenium webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using below Configurations :

> Selenium webdriver 3.3.0 with C# language
>
> Geckodriver V0.15.0
>
> Firefox 45.9.0.

When i use Actions method to use `Doubleclick()` function. I've met an error `System.NotImplementedException: performActions`. This mean i can't use `perform()` function for this action.
Could anyone help me about this thing?

Below is the code :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using cExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

IWebElement date = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='grid']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[61]"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); // Action method in interactions Lib use for DoubleClick()
builder.DoubleClick(date).Build();
builder.Perform();
date.SendKeys("Time");
```

Below is error :

> Result StackTrace:     at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>
>   atOpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IActionExecutor.PerformActions(List`1
>   actionSequenceList) at OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions.Perform()
>   at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in
>   C:\Users\TUM1HC\Desktop\Visual
>   Studio\MasterTool\MasterTool\UnitTest1.cs:line 55 Result Message: 
>   Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   System.NotImplementedException: performActions

Comment: It's quite unclear what `Actions` GeckoDriver currently implements, but it appears that `DoubleClick` is not supported in 0.15.0.

Here's the corresponding bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292178

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear what `Actions` GeckoDriver currently implements, but it appears that `DoubleClick` is not supported in 0.15.0.

Here's the corresponding bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292178

---

If possible, update to latest versions of GeckoDriver and Selenium WebDriver (maybe even Firefox). Your code works on my config (Selenium WebDriver 3.4.0, GeckoDriver 0.16.1, Firefox 53.0.3).

---

Also, from a code review standpoint, I prefer chaining multiple actions together, separating each individual action on it's own line, and keeping `build`/`perform` on the same line:

```
builder.DoubleClick(date);
builder.SendKeys("Time");
builder.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Thank you Budi! I have updated all element: Selenium webdriver 3.4, Geckodriver 0.16.1, Firefox Browser 52.1.1. But it is still not working now. This error maybe still stand at .perform() action. I have updated error report below. Could you please help me again? Thank you so much!

Comment: Added a small code example to improve your code. The stack trace looks the same to me, please ensure that you are using the newest GeckoDriver.

Comment: I've change code like you but the same error. I've used newest Geckodriver V0.16.1, selenium webdriver 3.4.0. Firefox browser 53.0.3(64bit). If i put perform() out like: builder.Build(); , the test can run without error but have no result of Doubleclick() action.

Comment: Yes, that's because `Perform()` executes the action(s) that we've built. You can try using ChromeDriver to see if the error still exists.